# TGW attachment to subnet in non routable overlapping space

Tags: amazon-vpc

I am building vpc with primary and secondary cidr . Secondary cidr having nonroutable space -100.64.x.x/27 which I am using for tgw attachment only . My question is whether can I leverage the same non routable cidr for other vpc for transitive routing ? I.e - can I use overlapping nonroutable cidr for tgw attachment ?